# Uniform convergence of series of functions 4

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, uniform-convergence

Some help with the uniform convergence of the next series:

a) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}sin(1+\frac{n}{x})$ for $x\ne 0$

b) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{sin(nx)}{n}e^{-nx}$ for $x>0$

c) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n$ for $0\leq x<1$

I've tried the M-test in a) and b) but i've failed, and the last one i tried to rewrite as quotient in the form $\frac{1-x}{1-x^m}$ for some m, but i also failed. Please I need understand how to prove or disprove the UC of these series,  anyone can give a hand for this?

Comment: $e^{x+iy} = e^{x}(\cos(y) + i\sin(y))$ could be helpful for (b) and for both (b) and (c) the 'n' factor could be cleaned up by considering derivatives or integration.

Comment: But isn't true that before differentation and integration over a sum I've first have to prove the UC of the series?

Comment: @AlphaNumeric On b), It's correct use the following? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(nx)}{n}e^{-nx}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}e^{-nx}$ and for any $a>0$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}e^{-nx}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}e^{-na}$ , then aplly the M-test of Weierestrass and conclude the UC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the third one in this way:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}$

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}-x=\frac{x^2}{1-x}$

$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{x^2}{1-x}-x^2=\frac{x^3}{1-x}$

In general...

$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x}-x^{k-1}=\frac{x^k}{1-x}$

if you sum all the series on the left you have: $x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots+kx^k=\sum_{n=1}^{k}nx^n$ and, in the other side you have $\frac{x}{1-x}+\frac{x^2}{1-x}+\cdots \frac{x^3}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{n=1}^{k}x^k$. Now, taking $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}$ in both expressions, conclude.